# FInding $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ given a piecewise function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

We have been given $f(x,y) = -xy$ if $|y| \ge |x|$ and $xy$ if $|y| < |x|$. We need to show that both $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ exist at $(0,0)$, but both are unequal.

When I solve this problem in both the regions, I found both $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ to be $-1$ in first region and $1$ in second. But I needed to show that they exist and are unequal!

The definition of partial derivative I used was:

$$\left.\frac{\partial f(x,y)} { \partial x}\right|_{(a,b)} = \lim_{u\to 0}\frac{f(a+u, b)-f(a,b)}{u}$$

Comment: How did you get $1$ and $-1$? Applying your formula for $f(x,y)=xy$, I get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=y$

Comment: @andrei isnt that valid only for second region, ie $|y| < |x|$ ?

Comment: It is. Now apply it to the first region as well, and you get $-y$. For the other partial derivatives you should get $x$ and $-x$. Note that all these go to $0$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$

Comment: @andrei but what about the next derivative that we need to take?

Comment: You are tight. I did not notice the second index

Comment: The first-order partial derivatives are piecewise-defined functions of $(x,y)$. Apply the definition of partial derivative to them.

Comment: Ohh I realise! @amd It is that $f_{xy}(0,0)$ is $-1$ because we use the $|y| \ge |x|$ definition as $x=0$ and but $f_{yx}(0,0)$ will be 1 with same reasoning?

Comment: Please someone tell me is my last comment correct